# Переменные внутри стиля

Tags: php, css

Есть следующий **css** стиль:

```
?>
<style>
.fon2{
background: url(<?=$leff?>) no-repeat;
border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
margin-right:4px;
color: #898989;
font-size: 11px;
width: 96%;
}
</style>
<?
```

Как сделать, чтобы переменная `$leff` внутри `<style>` работала?

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно использовать расширение не .html, а .php

```
<? $leff = 'no-img.jpg'; ?>

<style>
.fon2{
background: url(<?=$leff?>) no-repeat;
border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
margin-right:4px;
color: #898989;
font-size: 11px;
width: 96%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Денис** ваш код работает только добавте в стиле высоту картинки например **height: 50%;** и укажите правильный адрес вашей картинки.

```
.fon2{
background: url(<?=$leff?>) no-repeat;
border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
margin-right:4px;
color: #898989;
font-size: 11px;
width: 96%;
height: 50%;}
```